# Step Over works unexpectedly in vs2010 during unit test debug?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Sometimes when I'm debugging a unit test in vs2010, Step Over (F10) will not just step over the instruction I'm in but just Continue (F5) to the next breakpoint or to the end of the test.

I was wondering why this happens. When it does I usually re-run the test up to the same point, and then it doesn't Continue, it Steps Over like it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Service Pack 1, it fixes this problem.  Download [is here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=75568aa6-8107-475d-948a-ef22627e57a5), pick the right language if you use this link.  The list of SP1 fixes [is here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509), the bug you found is in the Debugger section:

> 556756: Debugger randomly treats "step-into" and "step-over" procedures as a "run to completion" procedure. (http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/556756/debugger-randomly-treats-step-into-and-step-over-as-run-to-completion)

Comment: awesome! Thanks! I was just looking at the SP1 download, but didn't know it included this too, I'll download it asap